# Hive Where clause with subquery - Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed

Tags: hive, subquery, where-clause, non-equi-join

I need to get all the record from tableA greater than cdc_date which is stored in another tmp_table

tmp_table has only one column cdc_date and only one record.

tableA has more the 5 million records.

My Hive query

```
Select count(*) from tableA as a 
where unix_timestamp((concat_ws('-',a.year,a.month,a.day,a.hour)),"yyyy-MM-dd-HH") > 
(select b.cdc_date from tmp_table as b)
```

I am receiving below error

```
Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'cdc_date': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed
```

Can anyone suggest how to active this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the sql -

```
Select count(*) from tableA as a 
Left join tmp_table b
On unix_timestamp((concat_ws('-',a.year,a.month,a.day,a.hour)),"yyyy-MM-dd-HH") > 
b.cdc_date
```

Comment: In my environment hive.mapred.mode is set to strict, so cartesion products are disabled.                                                                                                                                 
I tried using left join, still I am receiving the same error "Cartesian products are disabled for safety reasons.

Comment: its not really Cartesian join - its just left join. YOu can change it to normal join and see ?

Comment: I tried normal join as well. Still it says "Cartesian products are disabled for safety reasons". is it because we are trying to do non-equi join?

Comment: strange. does any normal joins like `select a.id from a join b on a.id = b.id` works?

Comment: No, I want records greater than cdc_date. I am trying with clause now.               
With t1 as (select cdc_date from tmp_table) Select count(*) from tableA as a where unix_timestamp((concat_ws('-',a.year,a.month,a.day,a.hour)),"yyyy-MM-dd-HH") > t1; but this query throws "Invalid table alias or column reference 't1'" error

Comment: i think your sql is wrong it should be ` With t1 as (select cdc_date from tmp_table) Select count(*) from tableA , t1 as a where unix_timestamp((concat_ws('-',a.year,a.month,a.day,a.hour)),"yyyy-MM-dd-HH") > t1.cde_date;`

Comment: @KoushikRoy Non-equi joins in Hive are implemented as  CROSS  join + filter, this is why your query also does not work. Because under the hood it is cross join. And query in your last comment:`... from tableA , t1 as a where  ...  ` - this is also the same CROSS join because join without ON is a cross

Comment: Some reading about joins https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843832/2700344 And this about theta joins https://stackoverflow.com/a/65788740/2700344 Also execute EXPLAIN for query with non-equi-join and you will see, it is CROSS-join in the plan.  Cross-joins are inevitable, you can not restrict them and be happy. there are many cases when you really need cross join. Your query with single-row table is such example when you really need cross-join

Comment: I understand. The last SQL was a modification of OP's sql. I was correcting some syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Cross join with single row table:

```
Select count(*) 
 from tableA as a 
      cross join tmp_table b
where unix_timestamp((concat_ws('-',a.year,a.month,a.day,a.hour)),"yyyy-MM-dd-HH") > b.cdc_date
```

Comment: In my environment hive.mapred.mode is set to strict, so cartesion products are disabled.

Comment: @KalpanaSrinivasababu Without cross join enabled the only way is to use parameter with  cdc_date fetched in another session, it creates unnecessary complications. Better set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;